# How to use post author ID to compare in WP_Query loop for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically I need to output all posts from the current user logged in. So I am trying to do this in WP_Query, the only problem I am having is for the "meta_key" and what I actually put there, is there a meta_field for the post author's ID? How should I approach this?

```
$recentAnimeEntry = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,  
        'post_type' => 'anime_list_entry',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => DESC,
        'meta_key' => 'author_id?',
        'meta_value' => $current_user->ID,
        ));
```

As you can see for `meta_key` I don't know the actual meta key for the author, I don't think wordpress actually has a meta field for the author in it's post meta. So how should I actually approach this? Is there any other way? I don't want to retrieve all the posts and then use some sort of if condition to display the current user's post, because that will slow down the site, especially if there are a lot of posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `author` parameter, not a `meta_key` parameter at all.  See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters).

Behind the scenes, a post's author is stored in the `wp_posts` table.  `meta_key` is only used when the values are stored in the `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: Realized this a bit after I posted the question lol. This is basically how you'd want to do it :) Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found your solution.  Thanks for accepting my answer.